# I keep getting error with my code. I want tselect rows for AR, AL, CA,

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

1 to 5 of 5 entriesFilter

I keep getting error with my code. I want tselect rows for AR, AL, CA, . Then, utilize stacked bar plot, to stack vote percentages for Trump, Clinton, Johnson, and Others. Please see 'pct_clinton', 'pct_trump', 'pct_johnson', 'pct_other' columns. Make sure that your x tick labels are those four states above.

[image: Image of the Table]

```
df = df[['state', 'pct_clinton', 'pct_trump', 'pct_johnson', 'pct_other']].dropna()

df.head()

df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=['red', 'skyblue', 'green'])

x= states['AR', 'MI', 'CA', 'WI']

plt.xticks('states')

plt.ylabel('')
```

Comment: Where do you set the variable `plt`? You never use `x` anywhere.

Comment: What is `states`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# Restrict the list of states
STATES = ['Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California']

ax = df[df['state'].isin(STATES)].plot(x='state', kind='bar', rot=45, xlabel='States')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]